# ConvertApi and Google Script:I sometime get an "error 500 while mergin' pdf " but not always

Tags: google-apps-script, convertapi

Ciao,
I am using convertapi to merge pdfs in a Google App Script ( pdfs are created from email attachment received from customers of ours ).

The code is

```
BLA BLA BLA BLA   
while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        formData['Files[' + index + ']'] = file.getBlob();
        index++;
    }
    var options = {
        'method': 'post',
        'payload': formData,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://v2.convertapi.com/pdf/to/merge?Secret=MIOCODICE', options);
```

My problem is that this code works 95% of the times. Sometimes I receive an error code 500 with no additional explanation.

EDIT: when I get the error code che response is "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong. We have been notified about the problem and we will try to fix". Not really helpful.

Error is triggered always from the same customers so the error is connected to the type of pdf they send me.
The pdf which triggers an error seems fine, I have no problem in downloading/printing/viewing it.

EDIT: is not a network/temporary problem because I always have this merging problem with the same pdfs, no matter how many times I re-try.

The strange thing is that the files are correctly merged via web convertapi interface ( https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-merge ) but still, no way to have them merged via script.

Any suggestion on how to fix this strange behaviour?

Comment: Could you share an example of a pdf that triggers this error?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKqldmEUyl7ffwwXdmpaTMnBlKXrIvnx/view?usp=sharing


https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sSOSal7c4DsX2l0bG_L0zCs8BOEt0nNg/view?usp=sharing


I always have errors trying to merge these two files with the gscript code.
No problems using the web interface

Comment: What is send in response body when you get 500? The API returns Status Code, which you provided but also the body where explains why you got 500.

Comment: Always retry failed conversions 3X after 1s, 5s, 15s to avoid network and temporary issues.

Comment: I only got problems with the first of these files. It seems to be corrupted in some way. Interestingly, if the file is downloaded from Drive and uploaded it again, it works correctly (the same does not happen if a copy of the file is created with [File.makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopy). I'd just do that, specially considering that this happens in a small minority of cases. Would that be a valid workaround? (second file is working correctly for me)

Comment: Probably when downloading the pdf, it is somehow fixed, and this would explain why the web interface of convertapi works.

Comment: Probably when downloading the pdf, it is somehow fixed, and this would explain why the web interface of convertapi works.
I just found that sometimes customers send me pdfs that looks good, but are somehow flawed.Sometimes downloading &uploading them works, sometimes is not enough.
Probably I have to turn them in png and back to pdf AND THEM merge them.

Comment: @CaglianoLc Are you sending these google drive URL for conversion? They are not directly connected to PDF file, this is PDF file preview, that's why ConvertAPI Merging PDF fails.

Comment: Tomas: I am not trying to send those urls. They were only for you to understand the problem.
To Convert Api I send the file themself and 95-97% of the times it work flawlessly